# Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.0, request when needed

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

So i have this code

```
func requestMSG(){
    if uID != nil {
        let parameter: Parameters = [
            "id" : self.uID!
        ]
        Alamofire.request("http://front\(randomServer).omegle.com/events", method: .post, parameters: parameter).responseData { (response) in
            if let check = response.error{
                print(check.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        Alamofire.request("http://front\(randomServer).omegle.com/events",method: .post , parameters: parameter).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.value != nil {
                print("This is response: \(response)")
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as? [[String]]
                    if JSON?.count == 1{
                        if JSON?[0].count == 2{
                            print(JSON?[0][1] as Any)
                            self.chatLog.append((JSON?[0][1])!)
                            self.chatTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Later, i trigger a "Timer" that is requesting some info from "/event".
Response is looking like this

```
This is response: SUCCESS: <null>
This is response: SUCCESS: <null>
This is response: SUCCESS: <null>
This is response: SUCCESS: <null>
This is response: SUCCESS: (
        "hiii there"
Optional("hiii there")
This is response: SUCCESS: <null>
This is response: SUCCESS: <null>
```

It's requesting 1 time per second. But...

I want to send a request to server ONLY when it have something to show, in this example, a message from a user.

How i'm supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to get messages only when a new one is sent ? Like know when a message has been set ?

If that you mean, think you could use **Push Notification** and refresh only when a notification of message is received. Unless you won't be able to know when you'll need to do your request.

You could also use socketIo to make real time request (but your server side needs to be in NodeJs)

I think the best solution is to use the notification, to handle tin your app and request messages when it's received.

Hope it helps...

Pierre